# How to use JasperReportsPdfView without xml config

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

I would like to have a controller method returning a PDF from a JasperReports jrxml file, without using any xml configuration.

I would like to use a `JasperReportsPdfView`. Is this possible at all? I know it can be done with only Java code like in this blog:

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-3-mvc-jasper-integration_22.html

But I believe it must be possible with less code :-)

Here some example-code which does **not** work unfortunately.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/pdfreport", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
public JasperReportsPdfView getPdf() {

    // does not work like this, unfortunately
    final Person p = userService.getUserById("the id");

    final JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
    view.setReportDataKey("person");
    view.addStaticAttribute("person", p); // ??
    view.setUrl("report.jrxml");
    return view;
}
```

Thanks for any pointer.

**Edit:** This is my working solution:

```
@Autowired 
private ApplicationContext appContext;

@RequestMapping(value = "/test/pdfreport", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/pdf")
public ModelAndView getPdf() {
    final List<Map<String, Object>> users = userService.getUsers();

    final JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
    view.setReportDataKey("users");
    view.setUrl("classpath:report.jrxml");
    view.setApplicationContext(appContext);

    final Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("users", users);

    return new ModelAndView(view, params);
}
```

It's important to include the `spring-context-support` package to your project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me:

```
@Autowired private ApplicationContext appContext;
@Autowired private DataSource dataSource;

@RequestMapping(value = "/pdf", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getPdf() {
    JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
    view.setJdbcDataSource(dataSource);
    view.setUrl("classpath:report.jrxml");
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("param1", "param1 value");
    view.setApplicationContext(appContext);
    return new ModelAndView(view, params);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll try it out and let you know my results.

Comment: It looks like I am missing a jar... which I can not find for Spring 4.0. The missing class is: org/springframework/ui/jasperreports/JasperReportsUtils Could it be that your code example is based on an older version of Spring ?

Comment: i'm using 4.0.3 version of spring... spring-context-support-4.0.3.RELEASE has given class